# Why doesn't INotifyCollectionChanged extend IList?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I've ran into the situation a couple of times where I want to observe a collection through the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, but also want to be able to access any of the collection's elements. The `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface doesn't provide any way to access the elements, except for those that are involved in the change event (which (usually) are contained in the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`).

Now here's my thinking:

1. We know that whatever implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` is a collection (d'uh).
2. Since the `NotifyPropertyChangedEventArgs` contains indices indication the location of the change, we know that the elements can be accessed by index.

A collection that can be accessed by index is a list, so it seems to be that it would make sense to require that any `INotifyCollectionChanged` implementor also implements `IList`. This could easily be done by letting `INotifyCollectionChanged` extend `IList`.

Does anyone know why this is not the case?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to look up the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) software design principles, specifically the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

You asked why the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface does not also extend the `IList` interface. Let me answer it with a counter question using the Liskov Subsitution Principle:

> Can I say an `INotifyCollectionChanged` is an `IList`?

No I don't think so, for the following reasons:

1. `INotifyCollectionChanged` conveys the meaning that classes implementing this interface need to notify their users if its underlying collection was changed, whether that underlying collection is an `IList` or `ICollection`, or even `IEnumerable`, we do not know. It's different concept of an `IList` interface, which is simply an `ICollection` with an exposed [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewthkb10(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. You mentioned `NotifyPropertyChangedEventArgs` (which I believe you meant `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` instead) exposes properties of the indices indicating at what position the collection is changed. However this does not mean these properties necessarily expose the items through the indexers of `IList`. It can be an arbitrary number, a magic constant, whatever. It is up to the implementing class to decide how to expose the indices.

To demonstrate this, please take a look at my custom class that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`:

```
public class MyCustomCollection : INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    // This is what I meant by the "underlying collection", can be replaced with
    // ICollection<int> and it will still work, or even IEnumerable<int> but with some
    // code change to store the elements in an array
    private readonly IList<int> _ints;

    public MyCustomCollection()
    {
        _ints = new List<int>();
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public void AddInt(int i)
    {
        _ints.Add(i);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
            NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move, 
            (IList)_ints, 
            _ints.Count,
            _ints.Count - 1));
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = CollectionChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: To me, your answer basically boils down to 'just because there are indices in the EventArgs doesn't mean you can actually use them'. Then why are the indices there?

Comment: @Steven, you focused on the second point of my answer which is not my intent: the main reason why `INotifyCollectionChanged` does not extend `IList` is "`INotifyCollectionChanged` **is not an** `IList`". My second point simply illustrates that the index properties is an **abstraction**, not a **mechanism**

Comment: The `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` indices are not always set, for instance in the case of an ICollection that is not an IList. See Stephen Cleary's [Interpreting NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/07/interpreting-notifycollectionchangedeve.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know why, but I see reasons for that decision (without any knowledge of the decision – it’s just my opinion):

1. Implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` this way follows the principle of role-interfaces (the change notification is described rather than the object) Please see @rexcfnghk post for that!
2. Only the changed elements in the `EventArgs` are represented as an `IList<T>`, that does not mean that the collection itself needs to be a list

To conclude, they made a decision to make the default collection with change notification a `Collection<T>` using an interface that allows that was required.

Comment: `Collection<T>` implements `IList<T>`, so that argument is invalid. And if the collection does not have to be a list, then how are we supposed to use the indices that are given in the EventArgs?

Comment: @Steven, if the underlying collection is not an `IList`, the indices can simply calculated using a simple `for` loop.